# CAST to TIMESTAMP field in Teradata

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I have timestamp stored in VARCHAR field in the format `Tue Jul 28 04:05:16 PDT 2020`.
Can I cast it to a timestamp(0) field in Teradata ?

Comment: Is the format of the VarChar always the same fixed length?

Comment: Yes. Length & Format is expected to be same always. Thanks

Comment: Teradata doesn't recognize time zone descriptors like PDT; you would have to remove / adjust for that with a CASE statement or UDF. If it's always literally the letters PDT (and never PST or EDT, for example) then `to_timestamp(fld, 'dy mon dd "PDT" hh24:mi:ss yyyy')` should work. But CAST won't like the day of week or having the time between the month/day and year (in addition to the time zone descriptor issue); you'd have to SUBSTRING and concatenate to rearrange the components.

Comment: Another question, can you check if PDT is only used for the daylight saving part (summer) and PST for the rest (winter).